# Improving my proof for question 1.1.2 Elementary Number theory by Rosen.

Tags: number-theory

> 1.1.2 Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then there is a smallest positive  integer of the form $a-bk,\; k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Let $S$ be the set of integers of $a-bk$, then because positive integers has a least element, then any subset has a least element. Thus, there exist a least element of $S$.

My problem is that $k$ can be any integer like 500.  Thus if $a=2$ and $b=3$ then the $S$ can not have a least element.  How do I restrict $k$ to be only the solutions which $S$ will be positive?

Comment: Note that it says $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. so $k$ is allowed to be $0$ or negative. An the case $a=2,b=3$, the smallest positive value of $S$ is reached when $k=0$.

Comment: thought that I had to show for very $k$ possible.

Comment: No, $k$ here is a variable. So if we can show that there is a $k$ such that $a-bk$ is $\gt 0$ (easy) then by the least number principle, there is a $k$ for which $a-bk$ is the smallest positive it can ever be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can denote by $S$ the set of all *positive* integers of the form $a-bk$. Then you only need to show that $S$ is not empty.

Comment: proving for any $k$ is not needed.